# Normal probability plot using info from a text file

Tags: r

I am quite new to R and I have a problem which requires the use of a text file as data and to create the Normal Probability plot of the data in the text file. I am confused on how to reference to the text file in R and use it as a parameter in the function `qqnorm()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the text file (example.txt) is a table and you want to open it as a data frame, you can open the file with the command `df<-read.table("example.txt")` and thereafter continue to work in R. Your data is now in `df`.